# Error occurs while trying to sign in via email and password(Firebase)

Tags: android, firebase, sign

I am creating android app with firebase..If i want to sign in via email and password app shuts down..Register part is working only sign in part is problem.
So Please help me to fix this problem

```
 package com.example.developer.uber;


    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener {
    RelativeLayout rootLayout;
Button btnSignIn,btnRegister;
FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference users;


@Override
protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
    super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(
            new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
            .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Arkhip_font.ttf")
            .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
            .build()
    );
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    users = db.getReference("Users");

    rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.rootLayout);
    btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnSignIn = findViewById(R.id.btnSignIn);
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.btnRegister:{
            showRegisterDialog();
            break;
        }
        case R.id.btnSignIn:{
            showLoginDialog();
        }
    }
}


private void showRegisterDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("REGISTER");
    dialog.setMessage("Please use e mail to register");
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View register_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_register,null);

    final MaterialEditText edtMail = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    final MaterialEditText edtPassword = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
    final MaterialEditText edtName = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    final MaterialEditText edtPhone = register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);

    dialog.setView(register_layout);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("REGISTER", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


            dialog.dismiss();

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edtMail.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Please enter email address",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Please enter password",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edtName.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Please enter name",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPhone.getText().toString())){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Please enter phone number",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if(edtPassword.getText().toString().length() < 6){
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Password is too short!!!",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            //Registering new user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(edtMail.getText().toString(),edtPassword.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {

                            //Save user to db
                        User user  = new User();
                        user.setEmail(edtMail.getText().toString());
                        user.setName(edtName.getText().toString());
                        user.setPassword(edtPassword.getText().toString());
                        user.setPhone(edtPhone.getText().toString());

                        //User email to key
                        users.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                .setValue(user)
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                        Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Registered successfully",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Failed "+e.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLayout,"Failed "+e.getMessage(),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
private void showLoginDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("SIGN IN");
    dialog.setMessage("Please use e mail to SIGN IN");
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View login_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_login, null);

    final MaterialEditText edtMail = login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtEmail);
    final MaterialEditText edtPassword = login_layout.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);


    dialog.setView(login_layout);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("SIGN IN", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        btnSignIn.setEnabled(false);


            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtMail.getText().toString())) {
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter email address", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
                Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Please enter password", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            //Login
            final android.app.AlertDialog waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog(MainActivity.this);
            waitingDialog.show();

            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(edtMail.getText().toString(), edtPassword.getText().toString())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                            waitingDialog.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Xato emas welcomekirdi)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Welcome.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            waitingDialog.dismiss();
                            Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Xato"+e.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            btnSignIn.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
        }

    });

         dialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });

    dialog.show();
}
```

}

used libraries:

```
    dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
 core:3.0.1'

//Adding Libraries
compile 'com.github.glomadrian:MaterialAnimatedSwitch:1.1@aar'
compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.2'
compile 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
}
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

There is error in logcat:
com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzdd)' on a null object reference

And here my welcome activity

```
  public class Welcome extends FragmentActivity implements 
    OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;

//Play services
 public static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7000;
  public static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST = 7000;

 private LocationRequest mLoactionRequest;
 private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
 private Location mLastLocation;
 public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
 public static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
 public static final int DSPLACEMENT = 10;

DatabaseReference drivers;
GeoFire geoFire;

Marker mCurrent;
MaterialAnimatedSwitch location_switch;
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //Init view
    location_switch = findViewById(R.id.location_switch);
    location_switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MaterialAnimatedSwitch.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(boolean b) {
            if (b) {
                startLocationUpdates();
                displayLocation();
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(), "You are online", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                stopLocationUpdates();
                mCurrent.remove();
                Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(), "You are offline", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    drivers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Drivers");
    geoFire = new GeoFire(drivers);
    setUpLocation();
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                if(checkPlayServices()){
                    buildGoogleApiClient();
                    createLocationRequest();
                    if(location_switch.isChecked()){
                        displayLocation();
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

private void setUpLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        },MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }else{
        if(checkPlayServices()){
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            createLocationRequest();
            if(location_switch.isChecked()){
                displayLocation();
            }
        }
    }
}

private void createLocationRequest()  {
    mLoactionRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLoactionRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLoactionRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLoactionRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLoactionRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DSPLACEMENT);
}

private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)){
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode,this,PLAY_SERVICE_RES_REQUEST).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"This device is not supported",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
}

private void displayLocation() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);



    if(mLastLocation != null) {
        if(location_switch.isChecked()){
        final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
            Snackbar.make(mapFragment.getView(), "You are ", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            geoFire.setLocation(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid(), new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                //Add marker
                if (mCurrent != null) {
                    mCurrent.remove();
                    mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car))
                            .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                            .title("You"));

                    //Move camera to this pos
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 15.0f));
                    //Draw animation rotate marker
                    rotateMarker(mCurrent, -360, mMap);
                }
            }


        });
    }

    }else{
        Log.d("Error","Cant get location");
    }
}

private void rotateMarker(final Marker mCurrent, final float i, GoogleMap mMap) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    final float startRotation = mCurrent.getRotation();
    final long duration = 1500;
    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed  = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) 
      elapsed/duration);
            float rot = t*i+(1-t)*startRotation
   ;
        mCurrent.setRotation(-rot > 180?rot/2:rot);
        if(t<1.0){
            handler.postDelayed(this,16);
        }

        }

    });
}

private void startLocationUpdates() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLoactionRequest, this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    displayLocation();
    startLocationUpdates();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
       mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

 }

 @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location)  {
    mLastLocation = location;
     displayLocation();
 }
   }
```

Comment: Even I change versions 10.2.0 to 11.8.0 or 11.2.0 nothing chages..App shuts down

Comment: u run in emulator or devices ?

Comment: In both devices I checked..If i use debug i see -->it goes on success but while opening welcome .class crashes.

Comment: Connect your device via USB or run your application with the emulator an look in logcat what is wrong. Also you could show it for us we may help you.

Comment: ok then u post your Logcat error @JavohirRuzimurodov

Comment: Show your logcat error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                                 at com.example.developer.uber.Welcome.onCreate(Welcome.java:74)

Comment: I found solution to my problem..but in my Welcome activity mCurrent is null.it doesnt show my position on map. even i press switch button..I put Welcome activity to the question now

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.remove()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.developer.uber.Welcome$1.onCheckedChanged(Welcome.java:87)

Comment: geoFire.setLocation is not working..I check it while debugginf